# Horizontal concatenation of two multiline strings

Tags: python, string

I currently try to concatenate two multiline string horizontally. For example, having two strings str_a and str_b

```
str_a = """This is row \nAnd this is row\nThis is the final row"""
str_b = """A\nB"""
```

With the print return

```
This is row 
And this is row 
This is the final row
```

and

```
A
B
```

The print return of the resulting string after the horizontal concatenation should look like

```
This is row A
And this is row B
This is the final row
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```py
import itertools

for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(str_a.split('\n'), str_b.split('\n')):
    print(a, b if b else '')
```

**Output:**

```
This is row  A
And this is row B
This is the final row
```