# Python output possible to be to printed in another direction?

Tags: python, math, formatter

Is it possible for python output to be printed to the right?

My code:

```py
def arithmetic_arranger(input):
    for n in input:
        problem = (n.split())
        print(problem[0].rjust(4))
        print(problem[1].rjust(4))
        print(problem[2].rjust(4))
        print('----')
        answer = str(eval(f'{problem[0]} {problem[1]} {problem[2]}'))
        print(answer.rjust(4))
        print()

arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 698", "3801 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 49"])
```

[image: output]

Comment: [how to concatenate two formatted strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60876606)
or [Horizontal concatenation of two multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58173122)

Comment: Hello Callane, Using SuperStormer's advice, did you manage to make any progress in your string concatenation problem?

Comment: Yes, however the formatting for mine is harder than using zip for concatenation of 2 strings. Still trying to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

how you wanna do it is store the output and shape it like you want, and then print it,

exemple:

```py
nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
myString = ""
myString += "-----\n"
myString += "|" + nums[0] + "|" + nums[1] + "|\n"
myString += "-----\n"
myString += "|" + nums[2] + "|" + nums[3] + "|\n"
print(myString)
```

should output something like:

```py
-----
|1|2|
-----
|3|4|
```

looking at your code, you might be able to do the same kind of things

ps:
to make all things the same size,
use .rjust() or .format() function to make all line up perfectly ;)